# Menu items are not appearing in IE Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

For the below HTML Source code, I am trying click the Menu Item --Employer using Selenium Webdriver C# libraries. I am using the below xpath which is working fine in both chrome and firefox but its not working in IE. In IE its clicking the Menu item , but the menu items under menu are not getting populated

```
Xpath -- //aside[@id='left-panel']/nav/ul/li[2]/a/span
```

I tried multiple things like click and mouseover but nothing worked in IE . Not sure what else can I try to make it work

HTML Page Source Code

```
<document>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<body class="menu-on-top desktop-detected">
<header id="header">
<aside id="left-panel">
<div class="login-info">
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="active" style="background-color:grey;" title="Home">
<li title="Employer">
<a href="#" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<span style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Employer</span>
```

Things I tried

```
actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[title=\"Employer\"]"))).Build().Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Employer')]")).Click(); 
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[title=\"Employer\"] > a > span")).Click();
```

IE settings for Webdriver

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.EnablePersistentHover = false;
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior =
InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Accept;
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
var IEoptions = new InternetExplorerOptions(){
IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
};
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("location", options);
```

Comment: Sidenotes: 1. Why do you put a `span` into an `a` if it doesn't add anything useful? 2. Why are you using inline CSS? 3. That XPath is very brittle and will break your tests as soon as anyone changes the slightest thing in the HTML. It's usually better to have extra CSS classes and IDs for Selenium testing.

Comment: I have also tried using CSS it didnt work

Comment: I didn't mean to say you should turn the XPath into an equally complex CSS selector, but to add extra classes, e.g. `qa-link-employer` to the HTML and search for those in Selenium.

Comment: Correct ...but that would consume some time as the dev team will get it deployed in the next build ...any immedeate solutions/workaround which I can use....This query is not related to locators ...it working fine with both xpath and css i mentioned above on chrome and firefox.... the issue is with IE...its clicking but the menu is not appearing

Comment: Have you tried clicking the `a` element instead of the `span`?

Comment: Yes even tried that ...still the same issue